# IdentityServer4 impersonating a user from .Net core app

Tags: jwt, identityserver4

I have a .Net core app that runs as a background task. I want to be able to make calls to my web server on behalf of the users its processing data for (I guess this would be classed as user impersonation).

My web server uses IdentityServer4 and I can authenticate the app against it using the code in

https://identitymodel.readthedocs.io/en/latest/client/token.html

To summarize, define the client server side

```
    new Client
    {
        ClientId = "client",

        // no interactive user, use the clientid/secret for authentication
        AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ClientCredentials,

        // secret for authentication
        ClientSecrets =
        {
            new Secret("secret".Sha256())
        },

        // scopes that client has access to
        AllowedScopes = { "api1" }
    }
```

Create a auth token client side and use in an a http call

```
var client = new HttpClient();
var disco = await client.GetDiscoveryDocumentAsync("https://localhost:5001");
var tokenResponse = await client.RequestClientCredentialsTokenAsync(new ClientCredentialsTokenRequest
{
    Address = disco.TokenEndpoint,

    ClientId = "client",
    ClientSecret = "secret",
    Scope = "api1"
});
var apiClient = new HttpClient();
apiClient.SetBearerToken(tokenResponse.AccessToken);
...
```

This works, but when I user the bearer token I'm autheticated, but its not a 'user' thats logged in its the 'client' which has no claims.

So how do I get a bearer token that contains the claims I need to impersonate a user on the server?

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the **Authorization code flow** instead of the clients credentials flow to get a token for the desired user. Then you save that token locally and use that to access the API on the behalf of the user.

If you have short-lived tokens, you can request a refresh token so that you can get new access tokens when it expires.

clients credentials flow is only used for machine to machine communication where no user is involved.

Comment: If I use code flow, how do I go about getting the token, I guess via RequestAuthorizationCodeTokenAsync, but how do I specify the user I want to impersonate?

Comment: With the Authorization code flow flow, you let the user login. If you want to impersonate someone else that is not logging in, then its up to you to do your own hack, there is no "flow" or built in flow for that case, as far as I know.  Or you have to create your own tokens?